# Why doesn't this shape display on my view?

Tags: macos, swift, draw, paintcode

My problem is that I am unable to draw an oval in a  view controller using swift for an application being written for OSX.

I have the following code in a view controller:

```
class TouchController: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //// Color Declarations
        let color2 = NSColor(calibratedRed: 0.769, green: 0.364, blue: 0.364, alpha: 1)

        //// Oval Drawing
        let ovalPath = NSBezierPath(ovalInRect: NSMakeRect(70, 24, 145, 143))
        color2.setFill()
        ovalPath.fill()
    }
}
```

The code for the drawings were created by paint code. I am writing this for OSX in Swift. My question is why, when I compile the code is the oval not displayed?

Answer (score 2):

In Cocoa, implement the [`drawRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/drawRect:) method of `NSView` to draw in views. Using your existing code, see this Playground-compatible example:

```
import Cocoa

public class CustomOval : NSView {
    public override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let color = NSColor(calibratedRed: 0.769, green: 0.364, blue: 0.364, alpha: 1)
        let path = NSBezierPath(ovalInRect: NSMakeRect(70, 24, 145, 143))
        color.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }
}

var oval = CustomOval(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
```

See ["Drawing Shapes Using Bézier Paths"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH11-SW1) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I copied the class `CustomOval` into a file and then in my view did load put `var oval = CustomOval(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))` but it still didn't work. The link you have me had Objective-C examples but I'm writing in swift and don't know objective-c. Sorry for being a n0ob :)

Comment: @crossboy007 In this case, you could create an `NSView` in Interface Builder (say, within in your primary application window) and assign the Custom Class to `CustomOval`. If you're just starting, this kind of application development can be very challenging (and frustrating); it may be helpful to spend some time with introductory Cocoa texts before you dive in.

Comment: Yes, I should spend some time looking at that. But I very rarely do this kind of development, this is just part of a much bigger project :) I thought it would be very easy to add a circle to an `NSView` using the `NSViewController` file. Is it not possible to do it though the `NSViewController` file?

Comment: @crossboy007 Sure you can. Add `@IBOutlet weak var oval: CustomOval!` to your `NSViewController` and add a referencing outlet from `oval` to the controller (probably the "File's Owner").